# Visual studio saves nuget sources from local config in machine config

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

So I'm using Artifactory to host my NuGet packages and we have 2 different repos for 2 different solutions.

Each solution has a local Nuget.config file that adds its own source right after running the  command (which doesn't seem to work in VS) and disables the standard Nuget feed.

The problem is that if I open the Package Manager Settings in visual studio, choose the package sources sub section and click ok, VS will then save that custom repo in the %appdata%/Nuget/Nuget.config file. So now when I open the other solution it will see both repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. Ported it over to codeplex as https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3794. Thanks.